# After enabling checkpoint - org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.exceptions.UnfulfillableSlotRequestException

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have enabled checkpoint in flink 1.12.1 programmatically as below:

```
int duration = 10 ;
if (!environment.getCheckpointConfig().isCheckpointingEnabled()) {
        environment.enableCheckpointing(duration * 6 * 1000, CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE);
        environment.getCheckpointConfig().setMinPauseBetweenCheckpoints(duration * 3 * 1000);
    }
```

Flink Version: 1.12.1

configuration:

```
state.backend: rocksdb
state.checkpoints.dir: file:///flink/
blob.server.port: 6124
jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123
parallelism.default: 2
queryable-state.proxy.ports: 6125
taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 2
taskmanager.rpc.port: 6122
jobmanager.memory.process.size: 1600m
taskmanager.memory.process.size: 1728m
jobmanager.web.address: 0.0.0.0
rest.address: 0.0.0.0
rest.bind-address: 0.0.0.0
rest.port: 8081
taskmanager.data.port: 6121
classloader.resolve-order: parent-first
execution.checkpointing.unaligned: false
execution.checkpointing.max-concurrent-checkpoints: 2   
execution.checkpointing.interval: 60000
```

But it is failing with following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.exceptions.UnfulfillableSlotRequestException: Could not fulfill slot request 44ec308e34aa86629d2034a017b8ef91. Requested resource profile (ResourceProfile{UNKNOWN}) is unfulfillable.
```

If I remove/disable checkpoint, everything works normally. I have checkpoint requirement because, if my pod, gets restart, data which is being handled by earlier run gets reset.

Can somebody direct, how this can be addressed?

Comment: To add, i have tried with increasing slot to 5, "taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 5", but it didn't help. Also, what i observed, on console at 8081 port, it shows only 1 slot for task manager. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @david-anderson any suggestion for this ?

Comment: I was able to address it. Issue was, i was using k8s cluster. Its having more than two task managers pod running(Due to hpa it was 5 sometimes). Due to this, number of slots were insufficient. After managing hpa, using maxReplicas, problem is resolved.